# Anaconda is only available to root

Tags: python, python3, anaconda, jupyter, conda

I downloaded the **Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh** from official site and used the command:

```
sudo sh Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

To install. By default it installed inside '**/root/anaconda3**'. Now, I can only access python and conda when I use 'sudo su'. How can I make it available for myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have installed it on behalf of your user without `sudo` command.

Basically, follow these steps from [official installation docs](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/).

Answer (score 4):

Follow the uninstall process given in below link

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/

login as root user

```
sudo su
```

Install anaconda clean pkg

```
conda install anaconda-clean
```

remove all anaconda related files

```
anaconda-clean --yes
```

remove the anaconda folder (most likely created in root folder if you selected default)

```
rm -rf /root/anaconda3
```

remove the conda path configuration from bashrc file (use vi or gedit or nano editor)

And then run the installation file without the elevated user so that conda is accessible to your userid.